Limiting Excess Life Distribution in Discrete Renewal Process
I am getting ready for a Stochastic processes exams and one question in my book I get stuck on: compute the limiting distribution of excess life in the case of interarrival times Ti~Unif(1,2,3,…n).
I have no issues computing it for continuous interarrival time distributions using the formula $$1/\mu \int (1-F(u))du$$
And for discrete case, I tried summing $$1/\mu \sum (1-P(Ti\leq k))$$ and I also tried computing the integral on each unit internal using the floor function, but I cannot get a continuous excess lifetime distribution.
Since in my lecture notes it is specified that this limiting excess life distribution is continuous even if interarrival times are discrete, I know I am missing something, but what?
